# Terminal doesnt recognise changes, unless i write "make programm"

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal

I am a beginner and started learning C using VS Codium in Ubuntu. So I have a file named "programm1". And every time I try to run it in terminal with "./programm1" it doesnt recognise changes I made, unless I type "make programm1"
Is it supposed to be like this? Or is there ways to make it automatic, so I dont have to save every change I make with "make programm1"?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be like that. C is a compiled language, which means when you make a change it has to be recompiled and linked into an executable program. There's no way to make it *automatic*.

Comment: Quote: "so I dont have to save every change I make with "make programm1"?" Well, doing `make programm1` is **not** saving anything! It is compiling your (already saved) C source files into a program that you can execute afterwards.

Comment: *undefined reference* means it can't find the function, which means you must be missing a library. If `make programm1` works, why are you so set on not using it? If it works, then it must be supplying the proper libraries. If you want to see how, open the make file in a text editor or your code editor and see what it's doing that you're not.

Answer (score 0):

Your binary, `programm1` doesn't know how it is build.  Your build system, in this case, `make` specifies how to build your binary.  As you found that you can execute a build manually.  This is how I prefer to work (and in nvim I have the plugin ale enabled for real-time feedback).

Linux has a mechanism called inodify that allows a program to be notified of file system changes.  You may want to check out wrappers for the API including the packages `entr`, `inotify-hookable` and `inotify-tools`.

Another option is to configure your editor to run make for you when you save a file.